# How to store a huge matrix into database

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I plan to use PostgreSQL to store a huge matrix.

The structure of the dataset is like below:

1. It's a 20,000 * 20,000 matrix
2. Each element in the matrix has 5ish
   records to describe the features of the interactions between two
   nodes.

Is there any way to construct the database to make it easy to store and efficient to query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

My first advice would be to design you table with the column and row of each matrix element.

Eg. table = {**row,column**,record1,record2,record3,record4,record5}, with {**row,column**} been the primary key.

Hope it helps.